# Auto number after reset count for each different column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server management studio 2014.

I have 2 tables: Country and locations.

Country has a property Id and other columns.

Locations has a property Id, LocationNumber, CountryId.

In the old application it saved the data wrong for locationNumber when you would delete one.

So I am trying to reset all the location numbers and insert it again.

Let's assume I have this dataset:

Locations:

```
Id | LocationNumber | CountryId
-------------------------------
1  |        1       |     1
2  |        3       |     1
3  |        1       |     2
4  |        4       |     2
```

Now I want to reset the locationNumber per countryId so it would become this dataset:

```
Id | LocationNumber | CountryId
-------------------------------
1  |        1       |     1
2  |        2       |     1
3  |        1       |     2
4  |        2       |     2
```

It should be done with a query and not with increment properties.

Thank you, Brent

Comment: Are you just referring to "gaps" created by autoincrement/identity/sequence-generated columns? If so, this is expected behaviour, nothing to worry about, and really should be left alone. Gap-free sequences are a "bad thing", because you must serialize everything behind the sequence! (No concurrent udpates = a bit like a single-user database.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```
Select Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CountryId ORDER BY LocationNumber ) 
AS LocationNumber, CountryId FROM Locations
```